# Change icon in button if (condition)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button

I have a button with icon and text inside.

```
<Button
...
android:drawableStart="@drawable/my_button"
android:text="ABC"
...
/>
```

I would like to change icon from code if condition exists.

```
if (condition)
   setIcon1()
else
   setIcon2()
```

It has to be a button otherwise the layouts will split up.

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to set a drawable on a View in code?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way:

```
Button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
        R.drawable.my_button,
        R.drawable.my_button,
        R.drawable.my_button,
        R.drawable.my_button
    )
```

I recommend you to have a look on [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/bQu64DmaNn8) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you :) This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.profile_aadhar );
    binding.btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null);

     position to set
     Note setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( left, top, right, bottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/my_button"
    android:text="ABC"
    />



if (condition)
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1); 
else
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img2);
```

It will work.